# Deducing Lindemann-Weierstrass from Baker's theorem

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

I'm aware that Baker's theorem with $n=1$ (for one algebraic number only) follows from that of Lindemann-Weierstrass.

It is also often mentioned that Baker's result is a generalization of Lindemann-Weierstrass's.

**How do you prove that implication?**

Any reference or sketch for a proof would be appreaciated.

Comment: Lindemann's theorem is generalized by the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. Lindemann's theorem and the Gelfond-Schneider theorem are generalized by Baker's theorem. The Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem and  the Gelfond-Schneider theorem are extended (supplemented) by Baker's theorem, and all of these theorems are generalized by Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: @IV You did not explain why Baker theorem extends L-W.  I am interested in an argument for that.